# Get "No route to host" when trying to connect to a host whose IP is already set in /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, dns

In `/etc/hosts`, I've set the IP for a domain I'm going to connect.

This domain is resolvable even if I don't set its IP in `/etc/hosts`.

I can `ping` it, or use `requests.get` to send request to it, it works as expected.

But I can still see `[Errno 113] No route to host` in error log.

What could be the reason of this?

Comment: What program or library is producing the error message? We need more details, please.

Comment: @neersighted I am using the `requests` library in Python.

Comment: What is generating the error log? If requests can successfully make requests to the domain, what is the isssue?

Comment: @neersighted No, I didn't say anything about "successfully make requests to the domain". Of course it failed, and the error is caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 113] No route to host

Comment: > I can ping it, or use requests.get to send request to it, it works as expected.
Have you tried using the bare IP?

Comment: @neersighted I mean it works most of the time, but fails once in a while with `No route to host`.

Comment: That sounds like a networking issue to me. Is the IP globably routable? Or is it local to your network. If it's globably routable, try leaving a `ping` running a few hours and see how much loss you get. `mtr` is also a good diagnostic to use if you have access to a nix system.

Comment: @neersighted It's not local to my network. In fact, it's a service server of one of our partners. I'll trying `ping`ing it for a long time and see what happens. Thx.